# Linq-to-sql: Datacontext - missing table issue

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have issue with table "Reality" which is not found, when I type "db" and press dot it is not suggested to me and even when I type it manually it is not found.

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var query = db.Reality
```

I also could not see it in Object browser

[image]

Even when object "Reality" is alone showed in object browser. Connection to database should be fine and table is correctly displayed in Linq-to-Sql class. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Reality` is the entity. The `Realities` property on the `DataContext` is a reference to the `Reality` table. It's type is `Table<Reality>`.

I dont see any problem here.

Comment: Correct, I found solution, "Reality" table is changed automatically to "Realities", my simple mistake :)